# Fiberglass Shower Drain Removal

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent, remodeling, demolition

1974 Condo on a post tension concrete slab. This was an original fiberglass shower enclosure. I can’t figure out how to remove this drain.

Any advice is appreciated.

[image: Drain]

[image: Drain Closeup]

Comment: Are your drain pipes PVC or cast iron? If PVC it could be pressed on with an o-ring. I assume you tried pulling it up.

Comment: Try turning anti-clockwise, which could be "tap the scrap of shower flooring the right direction with a hammer" - 48 years of corrosion might be a bit tough to get past.

Comment: DWV are black ABS- I ask before I wanted to start whack’n on it. Being a post tension slab I would prefer not to damage the pipe! I’ll put some force into it and see what happens.

Comment: Force within reason - *tap* with a hammer and look for progress, not *beat* with a hammer until something breaks. And it might just cause the floor scrap to spin on the drain fitting. But it would be an approach to try. May be worth throwing some vinegar or CLR at the hard-water build-up, corrosion, soap-scum, whatever to see if that makes anything more obvious. I expect threads, and I *think* I see threads...

Comment: Understood - and I think I’ll take your advice and let it soak in some CLR for a day - I have plenty of other stuff to keep me busy! Thanks for the tips.

Comment: If you can see the part that should turn, cut through that with an angle grinder (or dremel + patience), stopping where it joins the piece you’re preserving. Then a chisel/pry bar in the slot might separate it enough to release a bit and unscrew. Patience here will pay off in preserving the pipe left behind.